# How to run a extension in the windows and tabs that will be open

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension to count the number of stylesheets.
When the icon is pressed, the stylesheets of all opened windows or tabs are shown.
However, the extension has no effect on the windows and tabs that are opened later.
How can I solve it ?

**manifest.json**

```
{
 "name": "StyleSheets counter",
 "description": "It counts the stylesheets linked with the web page",
 "version": "2.0",
 "permissions": [
    "tabs", 
"*://*/*",
    "activeTab",
"debugger" 
  ],
 "background": {
 "scripts": ["background.js"],
 "persistent": false
},
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "SS Counter"
},
"icons": {
    "48": "on.png", 
"48": "off.png" 
},
 "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
executeScriptsInExistingTabs();
});

function executeScriptsInExistingTabs(){
    chrome.windows.getAll(null, function(wins) {
      for (var j = 0; j < wins.length; ++j) {
        chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(wins[j].id, function(tabs) {
          for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; ++i) {
            if (tabs[i].url.indexOf("chrome://") != 0) {
              chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, { file: 'counter_ss.js' });
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
}
```

**counter_ss.js**

```
var theSheets = document.styleSheets;
alert("Number of stylesheets: " + theSheets.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add [onClicked](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked) event listener with your function `executeScriptsInExistingTabs` as callback.

Answer (score 0):

I have already the solution, **for the new tabs** and **for the ones whose URL is changed**:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {
      //none is done here
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, info, tab) {
      if (info.status == "complete") {
          chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {file:'counter_ss.js'});
      }
});
```

The code inside

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener
```

is run both, **when the new tabs are open** and **when the URL of a tab is changed**. So to avoid duplication, none is done in the

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener
```

However, it must be there (altough empty).